# Why is $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1 = -i+n-1$?

Tags: summation

Why is $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1 = -i+n-1$?

I am having trouble understanding this result, we are summing up $1$ from $i+1$ to $n-1$ wouldn't that just be $1$?

Comment: Just check: How many summands are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}1=n-1$$ and $$\sum_{j=1}^{i}1=i$$ notice that $$\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}1-\sum_{j=1}^{i}1=n-1-i$$

Answer (score 2):

$j=i+1 , j=i+2 , j=i+3,.  ..., j= n-1 = i + (n-1 -i).$

You count from $1$ up to $(n-1-i)$, which are $(n-1-i)$ terms.

The sum is ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition

$$\sum_{j=a}^{b}1 = b-a+1$$

that is the number of summands, then

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1 = n-1-(i+1)+1=n-1-i$$

To convince yourself let try with some simple example

$$\sum_{j=1}^{3}1 = 1+1+1 = 3-1+1=3$$

Comment: How do we get the first definition? Why is that b-a+1?

Comment: Since by definition $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)=f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)$$ for $f(i)=1$ we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n 1=1+1+...+1=n-1+1=n$$ and $$\sum_{i=a}^b 1=1+1+...+1=b-a+1$$

Answer (score 1):

It's just the following: $$n-1-(i+1)+1=n-i-1$$

You can use $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ for the arithmetic progression: $$n-1=i+1+(x-1)\cdot1,$$
where $x$ is the needed sum.

Comment: How can we explain this in words? We are starting at i+1 and ending at n-1 and how does the 1 come into play?

Comment: You can use $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ for the arithmetic progression: $n-1=i+1+(x-1)1$

Answer (score 1):

Replace $1$ with $a_j$, so your sequence is $a_{j+1}+a_{j+2}+\dots+a_{n-1}$.

Now let $a_j=1\;\;\forall j\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

The sum becomes $1+1+\dots+1$, i.e. $n-i-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that summation goes from $(i+1)$ to $(n-1)$:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} 1=&1_{i+1}+1_{i+2}+\cdots+1_{n-1}=\\&1_{i+1}+1_{i+2}+\cdots+1_{i+n-i-1}.\end{align}$$
Thus, there are $n-i-1$ numbers $1$ added.